# Set all rows in a mysql column to null

Tags: mysql

I want to set all rows in a mysql column to the value "null" - as in literally put the text "null" in there. Here is the code I am using:

```
UPDATE lists SET url=null
```

How do I make it so that it actually put's "null" inside the table?

Answer (score 0):

After a little more thinking, I fixed it by doing:

```
UPDATE lists SET url='null'
```